# Why does bash clear OLDPWD when a child script is started?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

OLDPWD is exported and passed to any children, but bash apparently clears OLDPWD whenever a child script is started:

```
$ cd /etc
$ cd
$ perl -e 'print "<$ENV{OLDPWD}>\n"'
</etc>
$ ksh  -c 'echo "<$OLDPWD>"'
</etc>
$ bash -c 'echo "<$OLDPWD>"'
<>
```

Any way to work around that other than creating an alias or dotting the child script or exporting some other variable with the same value, whenever I want to use $OLDPWD in a child script?

** UPDATE 2015/11/26 **

I filed a bash bug report and got this reply from Chet Ramey, the bash maintainer:

> > Why does bash clear OLDPWD when a child script is started?
>
> Because a new shell does not have a `previous working directory'.
> It's supposed to be set by cd, and if you haven't executed cd, you
> don't have one.
>
> It seems reasonable to inherit OLDPWD if it names a directory, in
> the same way that the shell inherits PWD if it names the current
> directory, so we'll try that for the next bash version.

Comment: Chet must be very careful. This seems to be a nice features, but it can break a lot of scripts, whom expect an empty OLDPWD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably this is leftover behavior from long ago when bash first implemented `OLDPWD`.  The release notes for bash 2.03 alpha (in 1999) indicate that `OLDPWD` was previously not an exported variable.  If it was not exported, it would not be inherited by a child process.

Judging by the comment on this chunk from bash's source, the behavior is intentional:

```c
  /* According to the Single Unix Specification, v2, $OLDPWD is an
     `environment variable' and therefore should be auto-exported.
     Make a dummy invisible variable for OLDPWD, and mark it as exported. */
  temp_var = bind_variable ("OLDPWD", (char *)NULL, 0);
  VSETATTR (temp_var, (att_exported | att_invisible));
```

Though the release note indicates that making it exported was done to follow POSIX.2, `OLDPWD` does not appear in the list of [shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03) for POSIX shell.  It does appear in the description of [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html).  That does not mention if an initial value should be obtained from a parent process; there is no specific behavior which is required.

It does not appear to be a documented feature of bash; there are few comments to be found:

- *[Loss of OLDPWD in Erlang on MacOSX](https://gist.github.com/trynity/2986216)*
- *[... 'OLDPWD not set' ...](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r16733493-OLDPWD-not-set)*, pointing out that initially the child shell *has* no prior `cd` command to set `$OLDPWD`.

Comment: "no prior `cd` command"...I remember a shell on Solaris where `PWD` was not set upon shell entry.  I believe it was later fixed.

Comment: Based on bash's behavior, it appears that although OLDPWD is exported by bash properly, bash refuses to _import_ it into a new process (bash appears to `unset OLDPWD` upon entry).

Comment: The way to resolve whether it was intentional or merely a minor bug overlooked for 25 years would be to file a bug report.  Since the initial value of `OLDPWD` does not appear to be addressed by POSIX, the guiding constraint would be whether bash's developers intended to match the behavior of ksh, or not.